# GCC is missing in PATH variable in Fedora 17

Tags: linux, gcc, fedora

GCC is missing in PATH variable in Fedora 17.

Can anyone help us with the information like which location needs to be added in path to use gcc?

Have included /bin and /usr/bin. But gcc is not available in both location. But gcc is installed.

```
[root@localhost bin]# rpm -qa | grep gcc
libgcc-4.7.2-2.fc17.i686
avr-gcc-4.6.3-1.fc17.i686
[root@localhost bin]#
```

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: It has installed as part of initial Fedora 17 OS installation. I didn't install it gcc explicitly.

Comment: how do you know? try to install it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The gcc package is not installed in your system, as seen from your `rpm -qa | grep gcc` output.

`libgcc` and `avr-gcc` are not enough to be able to use plain `gcc`: `libgcc` is the gcc shared support library, while `avr-gcc` is a cross compiling version of gcc, which can be used to compile for the avr platform (it will provide the `/usr/bin/arv-gcc` executable.

You will need to explicitly install gcc with:

```
# sudo yum install gcc
```

Because by default the PATH is already containing /usr/bin, you will be able to just launch it like:

```
# gcc
```